# What is considered a small hand for shimano?

Tags: shimano, brake-levers

The new shimano r7000 offers two options r7025 and r7000 in the brake levers, the first one is for small hands.

What is considered small hands?

Comment: I don't remember any precise definitions of "small hand" in R7000 press releases, so the sizing probably boils down to subjective feel or people who tend to have small hands, like kids or persons of short stature.

Comment: It is hard to choose if you have to buy online and you don't have previous experiences with road brake levers. Shimano features it has "For riders with smaller hands", but I can'f find any recomendation: https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/shimano105-r7000/ST-R7025-R.html

Comment: Maybe email Shimano and ask for details? Like glove size or even precise hand measurements.

Comment: @Klaster_1 I've not been able to find an email to directly ask questions in shimano official website.

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably have to try it and see which is most ergonomic for you; even if you have large hands, the small hands lever may feel better. Older levers came with a rubber piece to stick in the brifter to adjust for smaller hands, but this has limited differences versus a different lever.

Most females would fit into the small hands group. Younger males up to some age might as well. Adult males of average or larger size would likely not.

Comment: I can't comment on the r7000 levers specifically, but i've helped a couple of riders adjust their shimano levers to minimum reach over the last few years.  I'd say anyone not wearing mens size large gloves should probably consider the smaller model.  At the end of the day if they cant be tried in advance i'd err on the 'too small' size as that's better than not being able to reach the brakes properly.

Comment: This shouldn't be too hard to try experimentally; go to a bike shop and try a woman's bike and a mens bike; the women's bike likely has the smaller levers for you to test.